# setText() is not working on inflated Text view

Tags: android

Following is the code here I was testing that when I inflate any particular widget then I cannot really do setText on it. it overwrites the text and returns the last string. Here in the output screen I can see five textview added from xml but the one programmatically   I am trying to set is not happening I see only one text from str[] i.e str[5] which is the last one in the array. Please let me know if i am able to explain my problem.

```
public class TestInflate extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View[] inflated = new View[5];
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        TableLayout myTableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflated[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testbutton, myTableLayout);

        TextView userName = (TextView)inflated[i].findViewById(R.id.myName);
        userName.setText(str[i]);//here i should get name but not getting
    }
}
String[] str = {"a","s","d","r","t"};
}
```

and my testButton.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TableRow"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/Name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
android:text="Name   :"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_weight=".25"
></TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/myName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="italic"
android:layout_weight=".5"
></TextView>
</TableRow>
```

and main.xml is

```
 <ScrollView
 android:id="@+id/Scroll"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
<TableLayout
 android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:clickable="true">
   </TableLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Edit- and teh optput is like this

```
My output is like this 
Name : t //str[5]  
Name : 
Name : 
Name :  
Name :
```

Comment: looks like the setText() on inflated widget is over written if it is in a loop. how do i overcome that?
If i do it just a single time it will work but if it is in a loop like above one it will not :(

Comment: It is really hard to figure out what you want to do.

Comment: You set 5 times the same TextView... That's normal you see only the last text isn't it ?

Comment: I think he wants to add 5 TableRows to the TableLayout?

Comment: In this case i think you have to make an array of inflated views and call setText(); separately from every TextView of view. i.e 'View views = new Views[5]; view[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testbutton, myTableLayout);'

Comment: @Rainer, yes you are right i want to add 5 table row and it is getting added also with the code I have written above. but text view is not getting updated as Nanis mentioned.

Comment: @Adil,did what you said  for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
        View[] inflated = new View[5];
        TableLayout myTableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflated[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testbutton, myTableLayout);
        
        TextView userName = (TextView)inflated[i].findViewById(R.id.myName);
        userName.setText(str[i]);//here i should get name but not getting
        } but it does not work :(

Comment: OMG..!! define the array outside the loop..! just initialize every object of your array inside the loop. view[i] =inflater.inflate(R.layout.testbutton, myTableLayout); and set their text and add this view to Layout inside the loop.

Comment: ohhhh my fault. array was by mistake inside the loop I did all this step by step but can you please say what do u mean by "add this view to Layout inside the loop" as it is already being infalted. As you can see from testButton.xml I have a textview called myName where I am setting the text with setText(str[i]) and now also same problem is there only one Text is filled with str[5] and rest all is empty.

Comment: My output is like this Name : str[5] (newline) Name : [empty} (newline) Name : [empty} (newline) Name : [empty} (newline) Name : [empty}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this time it is tested.
try this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String[] str = {"a","s","d","r","t"};


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TableLayout myTableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout);
        LayoutInflatedView myClasses [] = new LayoutInflatedView[5];
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
           myClasses[i] = new LayoutInflatedView(this, myTableLayout);
           myTableLayout.addView(myClasses[i]);
           myClasses[i].setUserName(str[i]);

        }


    }
}
```

where your LayoutInflatedView is:

```
public class LayoutInflatedView extends LinearLayout
{
    TextView text;    
    public LayoutInflatedView(Context context, ViewGroup table)
    {
        super(context);        
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_button,this);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myName);
    }
    public void setUserName(String text)
    {
        this.text.setText(text);
    }

}
```

Check this and let us know if any problem occures.

Comment: Hi Adil, as I told you that when I inflate testButton.xml into myTablelayout, then i am adding the textview to the layout, so when i do setText why do i add it again ? Please excuse me i it too simple.

Comment: I have edited my question with the view how my output is looking.

Comment: What do you want to do...!! Do you want to make a list , button or what..? Can you explain your expected output and the objective of the expected output...!

Comment: Okay. I have an array of strings (this is basically database entry) I want to see how many entries are there and what is the corresponding string entered there. Now as it is dynamic as I do not know how many entries is possible. I have to use layout inflater. I am adding one constant Text i.e Name : which gets added as I have shown in the output and other is the name stored in the database. I was seeing the same problem in my database coding so to test the problem I have written this small test code

Comment: and here also i see the same problem. here String[] str = {"a","s","d","r","t"};
 is nothing but is representing my database. Please let me know if I am could explain.

Comment: Hi i've not get you all.  but what i understand is you want to keep a record of entries stored in the data base. I've modified the code. I think it should work. have a look at this.

Comment: By doing this myClasses[i] = new LayoutInflatedView(context, myTableLayout); you are creating inflated view five times whihc is same as View[] inflated = new View[5];
 so it is back to the square same thing. create an array of inflated views. access them one by one and then do a set text to each of them right? which as good as

Comment: View[] inflated = new View[5];
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        TableLayout myTableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflated[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testbutton, myTableLayout);

        TextView userName = (TextView)inflated[i].findViewById(R.id.myName);
        userName.setText(str[i]);//here i should get name but not getting
    }
like this right?

Comment: @AdilSoomro I have a click listener on all the five view but only the last one is working. Could you just clarify that for me . Thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
      (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);
    textOut.setText(textIn.getText().toString());
    Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
    buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
     }});

    container.addView(addView);
```

YOu can also try this inside your for loop.
For Reference : [Look Here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/05/add-and-remove-view-dynamically.html)